# Node.js get mothod ? What does this "Blog.find().sort()means?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, backend

I was in node.js tutorial and teacher writed this code

```
app4.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    Blog.find().sort({createdAt :1})
        .then((result)=>{
            res.render('index',{
                title: 'Anasayfa', blogs:result})
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```

I didnt understand that what does "Blog" does and means in there, is it a object from a module or something else ? I asked teacher but he didn't response to me.
When I execute that code I receive error "Blog is not defined" that means first I gotto define Blog but how to define ? By bulding a module or file ?

I appreciate every response, thankk you for your time

Comment: Well, we can't see the rest of the code to know for sure, but `Blog` looks like it's probably a database collection.  You run `.find()` with no arguments on it to return all the items in that Blog collection and then you call `.sort()` on it to sort them by their `createdAt` property.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with the code shown, we don't know what it means either.  :-)

Whomever wrote the code will have to explain.  However, we can say that this type of pattern is typical for a database backend.

`Blog` is probably a *database model*.  Think of it like a *class* or type of object.  By calling `Blog.find()`, you're likely fetching all the blogs (or blog articles, whatever it is).  Then calling `.sort()` on that result set, you're sorting by the `createdAt` attribute.